# Unable to power on VMware

Tags: vmware

I installed VM ware recently now whenever i try to power on VMware it shows the below message:

"Not enough physical memory is available to power on this virtual machine with its configured settings.

To fix this problem, adjust the additional memory settings to allow more virtual machine memory to be swapped.

If you were able to power on this virtual machine on this host computer in the past, try rebooting the host computer. Rebooting may allow you to use slightly more host memory to run virtual machines."

I am not able to change the memory setting .It just shows an option to resume the virtual machine, All other options are disabled. I have by mistake increased the VM ware memory in run time .Could any one help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like your VM machine is in a suspended state. What you need to do is follow the steps [outlined here in this help ticket](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006111). Do these steps while vmware is not running. And once you do this, start vmware again and then you should be able to edit your memory settings.

Comment: yeah i got the problem solved. There was a VMX file . I removed everything between the quotation marks. It should look like:

checkpoint.vmState = "". Now its working fine thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these steps fixed it for me. I think VMWare Player is so brittle. There are so many ways it can fail to load. And instead of including a few tools to get a VM back into shape, all we get are cryptic error messages. I always feel like my data is in danger in the VM.

Comment: For me, running VMWare as administrator helped. The issue probably came from a Windows 8.1 update. Here are some other strategies that might help: http://www.petri.com/fixing-enough-physical-memory-available-errors-vmware-workstation.htm

Comment: Where is this VMX file? I don't see any anywhere and I'm getting fed up with the VMware website which is as reliable as its products.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After several extra steps it works now!

Answer (score 13):

For anyone who encountered this problem recently, please visit this link:

http://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2014/10/workstation-10-issue-recent-microsoft-windows-8-1-update.html

Go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features,then uninstall the  Windows 8.1 Update KB2995388 may help

--* Edit *--

The **Optional** Update for **Windows 8.1** for x64-based Systems (**KB2995388**)  published on 10/13/2014 may causes issues when running VMware Workstation on a Windows 8.1 host with it installed.
And a message saying "*not enough physical memory*" will be reported.

Because the VMware team hasn't fix the issue, you can follow steps below to uninstall the update to boot your virtual machine:

1.Go to **Control Panel** -> **Program**s -> **Programs and Features**, then select **View installed updates** at the top left corner.
2.Scroll down the list and locate **Update for Microsoft Windows (KB2995388)**, select it and click on the Uninstall button.
3.Follow the steps to finish the uninstallation.

In the comment list, someone also reported a fix from VMware communities:
Open the config.ini file located at C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Workstation.
Add this line:
`vmmon.disableHostParameters = "TRUE"`
Save & reboot your PC

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,I will add more datails.

Comment: I just fixed this by updating to the latest version: 
FILE NAME
VMware-player-7.0.0-2305329.exe

BUILD NUMBER
2305329

RELEASE DATE
2014-12-01

Comment: I'm running Windows 7, I tried ths config.ini edit, but its didn't work. I cannot see to power on my guest OS. I hadn't shut down correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Run it in Administrator mode in Windows 8.1. Probably a Windows Update... Deleting the suspended state didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you update to the latest vmware player or uninstall a windows update as well? just running in admin mode didn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 1):

Before proceeding with any alternative solutions/workarounds, please always double ensure you have updated to the latest version of `VMWare Player`.

My machine was running `VMWare Player, Version 6.0.*`, and this issue was occurring (*my local machine's Operating System **is** `Windows 8.1`*). The relevant error(s) were resolved after updating to the latest build currently available, `VMWare Player, Version 7.0` (*Please note: I did **not** have to remove/uninstall any Windows Updates/Features*)

Comment: Good call man. I'm glad i backed up all the files the help ticket told me to delete so I can resume my suspended vm without incident. I find that messing around in config files and deleting things is just gonna cause problems later.

Answer (score 1):

Just spent a few hours trying to get my VMware to boot. Power flickered off enough to shut down the computer while the VMware was in suspension and recieved this message.

Make sure the update isn't installed. Make sure to follow the accepted answer. What made it work for me was:

1. Right click on your development name tab
2. Click on "Manage" and then "Clean up disk"

It worked for me. I'm not sure why it worked, but it was able to fix my issue. Didn't need to restart.

Comment: It worked for me. I cleaned up C disk and then restarted Vmplayer from Administrator rights. It started resuming its state.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1. Close the VMware.
2. Select VMware icon.
3. Run VMware as Administrator.